# creating an opaque effect above a div using ::before

Tags: css, sass

[image]I'm trying to get a full width div which has the appearance of a same-height opaque div above it.

I can't use another div to achieve the opaque effect, so I'm using ::before.

Using the css below, I get the 'before' div but it is not opaque, it is like a diluted colour of the main-header div.

Edit:
In the image you can see the blue div with an opaque section above it, when we scroll images and text are still visible through it.

This has to be achieved using ::before if possible.

Edit:
I can get is using transform but it's not nice:

```
.main-header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #006ab1;
    width:100%;
    height: 60px;
    transform:translateY(60px);

    &::before {
        content: " ";
        bottom: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background: #fff;
        opacity: 75%;
        display: block;
        transform:translateY(-60px);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest what to change?

```
.main-header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #006ab1;
    width:100%;
height: 100px;

    &::before {
        content: " ";
        bottom: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: #fff;
        opacity: 75%;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the 'opacity: 75%;' should be on your .main-header

Comment: thanks, but That makes the whole thing opaque, I only want the top part generated by ::before to be opaque

Comment: It's hard to suggest something, maybe you should send some PrintScreen how is your result right now for better understanding.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by opaque as that can be interpreted as sold/not see-through.

Comment: Post updated with an image similar to what I'm trying to get.

Comment: For the blue &::before getting the opaque effect your .main-heade should have whether opacity or transparent background and push down &::before with z-index:-1;

Answer (score 0):

There's two possible ways:

### 1:. Use the `backdrop-filter` stlye on the `::after` psudo elememt

```css
.main-header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #006ab1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.main-header::after {
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  height: 100%;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  bottom: 100%;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
  <span>I am some content in the Main Header</span>
</div>
```

This is probably the better of the two.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

### 2:. Use the `filter` on the main header

```css
.main-header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #006ab1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">I'm some content</div>
```

But this makes the whole element blurry, and may not be what you want. You may want to constrain the `.main-header` element inside of a parent div to unsure no "leakage" if you use this option...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter